# jquery menu with saving position

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, menu

is any menu like treeview (open\hide each node), but after postback it restore the state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can use the jquery treeview plugin, here is the demo of that.](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/)

**Update based on comments:**

You can add styling like this. Create a stylesheet file like **whatever.css** and include in page where the treeview is used. Put this code in that stylesheet.

```
<style type="text/css">
.file,.folder
{
  font-family: 'Arial Black';
}
</style>
```

Comment: how can i set custom font on all menu items like Arial Black there?

Comment: @kusanagi: You will have to add some class to your elements and then apply css styles to that.

Comment: i don't well know how to work with css foe example how to add special class for node fonts